# Symfony2 - Mapping is invalid refers to the owning side which does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, yaml

I have two objects that are linked together:

*Child.orm*

```
OSC\UserBundle\Entity\Child:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: OSC\UserBundle\Entity\ChildRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        firstName:
            type: string
            length: 255
        lastName:
            type: string
            length: 255
        dateOfBirth:
            type: datetime
            column: dateOfBirth
        isPlayer:
            type: boolean
            default: false
        isCoach:
            type: boolean
            default: false
    manyToOne:
        parent:
            targetEntity: User
            inversedBy: children


    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

User.orm

```
OSC\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: OSC\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        lastName:
            type: string
            length: 255

        firstName:
            type: string
            length: 255

        streetNumber:
            type: string
            length: 255

        street:
            type: string
            length: 255

        province:
            type: string
            length: 255

        country:
            type: string
            length: 255

        homePhone:
            type: string
            length: 255

        mobilePhone:
            type: string
            length: 255
        isPlayer:
            type: boolean
            default: false
        isCoach:
            type: boolean
            default: false

        dateOfBirth:
            type: date
            column: dateOfBirth
    oneToMany:
        children:
            targetEntity: Child
            mappedBy: parent
    oneToMany:
        posts:
            targetEntity: OSC\BlogBundle\Entity\Post
            mappedBy: author

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I have the following error for which I've been banging my head on without any clue:

[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'OSC\UserBundle\Entity\Child' mapping is invalid:

*The association **OSC\UserBundle\Entity\Child#parent** refers to the inverse side field **OSC\UserBundle\Entity\User#children** which does not exist.*

The thing is that it is defined !

I have also noticed that using the command doctrine:generate:entities OSC, my attribute children is not created...

Comment: if you're using doctrine:generate:entities, first check whether the generated getters/setters are using "children" as opposed to "childs"

Comment: Why for `User.orm` you use FQN for class Post, while for `child.orm` you use only `User` for `manyToOne` relationship?

Comment: @DonCallisto Post is in another bundle while User is in the same bundle as child

Comment: @suke strangely, the children attribute is not created when I use generate:entities

Comment: @DonCallisto just so you know, I have the same problem with the posts attribute but I wanted to ask one question at a time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it ! I'm not 100% sure but it seems like you can't declare twice manyToOne, which seems logic. Removing it and putting everything in one block just like that, solved my problem !:

User.orm.yml

```
OSC\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: OSC\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        lastName:
            type: string
            length: 255

        firstName:
            type: string
            length: 255

        streetNumber:
            type: string
            length: 255

        street:
            type: string
            length: 255

        province:
            type: string
            length: 255

        country:
            type: string
            length: 255

        homePhone:
            type: string
            length: 255

        mobilePhone:
            type: string
            length: 255
        isPlayer:
            type: boolean
            default: false
        isCoach:
            type: boolean
            default: false

        dateOfBirth:
            type: date
            column: dateOfBirth

    oneToMany:
        children:
            targetEntity: OSC\UserBundle\Entity\Child
            mappedBy: parent
        posts:
            targetEntity: OSC\BlogBundle\Entity\Post
            mappedBy: author
```